# How to check if name already exists in Firebase Realtime Database (Firebase & JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to check if a name already exists on a Firebase Realtime Database that is structured as follows:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
const players = Firebase.database().ref("players");

function nameCheck() {
        console.log(name);

        players
        .orderByChild('settlement_name')
        .equalTo(name)
        .once('value')
        .then(snapshot => {
            if(snapshot.exists()){
                let playerData = snapshot.val();
                console.log(playerData)
                setError('Settlement name already exists')
                return playerData
            } else {
                console.log('Settlement name not found');
            }
        })
    }
```

Can anyone tell me why this function is not correctly identifying when a name exists? I am logging the name at the start of the function and it matches those on the database, yet it will only return that the name is not found.

Thank you kindly.

Comment: Values are case-sensitive. Are you sure you are comparing exact same name or so ?

Comment: Thanks for your response, @Dharmaraj - I have been comparing the exact names with case sensitivity and have found no results.

Comment: Thanks again, @Dharmaraj - it is returning 'null'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the **nested child path**, as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data?authuser=0#sort_data).

```
    players
      .orderByChild('settlement/settlement_name')
      ...
```

---

PS: In case you check if a name exists in order to use this name to create a new database node (if it does not exist), you should use a [Transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write?authuser=0#save_data_as_transactions).

Comment: That's done it! Champion. Thank you very much!